# Obtener URL actual para generar breadcrums

Tags: javascript, array, string

estoy haciendo un `breadcrum`, y necesito una mano para manejar strings de javascript. Tengo esto:

```
    const Breadcrumbs = (props) => {
    const elements = props.url.split('/');
    elements.shift();
    console.log(elements)
    return (
      <div className='breadcrums'>
        <Breadcrumb tag="nav" listTag="div">
           {
              elements.map((element,index) => {
                console.log(element)
                return <BreadcrumbItem key={index} tag="a" href={'/'+element} className='text-capitalize'>{element}</BreadcrumbItem>
              })
          }
      </Breadcrumb>
    </div>
  );
};
```

> En la variable `elements` se guarda un array que contiene cada una de las partes de la url, algo asi: `["profile", "edit"]` (en realidad me guarda un primer elemento vacio que elimino con .shift() )

Ahora, cuando yo hago el `.map` quisiera hacer lo siguiente:
Que el primer elemento se pase como está ('profile'), y que el segundo elemento se concatene al primero, me explico?

Yo en este momento, tengo un breadcrum algo como:

> Profile / Edit

Y el link de `profile` es `http://localhost:3000/profile`, mientras que el link de `edit` es `http://localhost:3000/edit`. Yo espero que sea `http://localhost:3000/profile/edit`

Muchas gracias

Comment: Si uso la funcion .reduce() puedo obtener algo como lo que quiero, pero no me doy cuenta como combinarla con el .map()

Answer (score 0):

lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

1. Declaré una variable `urlActual = ''` antes del return
2. Dentro del map le voy agregando en cada recorrido el valor actual de `element`: `urlActual = urlActual+'/'+element;`

   ```
    const Breadcrumbs = (props) => {
    const elements = props.url.split('/');
    elements.shift();
    const urlActual = '';
    return (
      <div className='breadcrums'>
        <Breadcrumb tag="nav" listTag="div">
           {
            elements.map((element,index) => {
            urlActual = urlActual+'/'+element;
            return <BreadcrumbItem key={index} tag="a" href={'/'+element} className='text-capitalize'>{element}</BreadcrumbItem>
          })
      }
      </Breadcrumb>
      </div>
     );
   };
   ```

Y este componente sirve para meter en cualquier página y pasarle por props la `url` actual, y generará automaticamente los links de cada miga de pan! Espero que le sirva a alguno! Saludos